# Angular 2: How property binding/interpolation works when data is changed in component

Tags: angularjs, angular

In Angular 1.x, the digest cycle use to take care of updating view when data is changed on scope. How does property binding and interpolation works in Angular 2 when data is changed in component?

Comment: https://hackernoon.com/the-mechanics-of-dom-updates-in-angular-3b2970d5c03d

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular2 has its own version of Zone (called **NgZone**) that take care of detecting changes. When NgZone detects a change is called an event called *onTurnDone*. Angular has a component called **ApplicationRef** that listens for this event to occur and when it does the *tick()* method (of the ApplicationRef) is called. The *tick()* method, at this point, is the responsible for the changeDetection cycle that updates the view.

If I've understood the question you have made, then maybe you'd like to read a post that goes deeper into this subject of the change detection strategy:
https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html

Comment: The link is very informative. This whole thing was bugging me for long. Thanks